After upgrading Jenkins to JDK 17 jobs don't create build.xml
We've upgraded our Jenkins controller to 2.462.2 running on Tomcat on Windows. In the process, we've upgraded all plugins to recent versions. All seems fine with upgrade. We also later tried switching from Java JDK 11 to JDK 17. All booted fine, everything seems to work, but I noticed that when I ran a few jobs and restarted, the history doesn't show the new jobs. When I investigate, I notice that there are no build.xml files in the builds folder under the job. If I run new jobs, the history shows the new job using a newer build number, but if I reload from disk that history goes away. When I switched back to JDK 11, the job does create the build.xml file and the history of the jobs run with JDK 11 stay in the history.
Tried running jobs under JDK 11 which were successful using the same plugins. Nothing is obvious in the logs. Several plugins were recently updated, but no configuration was changed from old versions running on JDK 11 to the new versions on JDK 11 then on JDK 17.
Here's a snip from log:
SEVERE [Executor #1 for WinAgent1 : executing Run_Checkmarx #19] hudson.model.Run.execute Failed to save build record
              java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to serialize hudson.model.AbstractBuild#culprits for class hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild
                             at hudson.XmlFile.write(XmlFile.java:223)
                             at hudson.model.Run.save(Run.java:2061)
                             at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1947)
                             at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
                             at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
                             at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:446)
              Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to serialize hudson.model.AbstractBuild#culprits for class hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild
                             at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:274)
                             at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.visit(RobustReflectionConverter.java:241)
                             at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:174)
                             at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doMarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:226)
                             at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:163)
                             at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68)
                             at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:59)
                             at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:44)
                             at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.start(TreeMarshaller.java:83)
                             at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.marshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:37)
                             at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:1303)
                             at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:1292)
                             at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:1265)
                             at hudson.XmlFile.write(XmlFile.java:216)
                             ... 5 more
              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private static final long java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.serialVersionUID accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @3ad497c4
                             at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
                             at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
                             at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)


Also, note this is on Windows. I added the env variable JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS with the values "-add-opens java.base/java.land=ALL-UNNAMED -add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED" hoping that that would provide the Java opts necessary. Though it seems that is picked up when I run java -version, the error persists when running a job.
Is there anything that needs to be configured after moving to JDK 17? I'm definitely missing something, but I'm desperate to solve this with JDK 11 support being dropped. I appreciate any help and can post a list of plugins, etc. if needed.

Try also adding --add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED.  The error trace you shared points to problems with serialization due to InaccessibleObjectException—this typically occurs when reflective access to certain internal Java classes is blocked in JDK 17.

I figured this out. As we are running Tomcat on Windows as a service, we need to use the Tomcat9w.exe tool to manage JDK Options. This is mentioned within the catalina.bat file. In the tool, there is a Java tab where I add my --add-opens statements, which I was able to do. I added those in the format:
–add-opens=java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
–add-opens=java.util=ALL-UNNAMED

Once I made the change and saved, I restarted the service and confirmed the log shows the parameters loading and my problem is now solved. All jobs are creating build.xml files without error using JDK17!
